# "Member for today" sounds just wrong. Let's think of something better

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, wording

I believe many will agree that "Member for today" sounds just wrong.

> [image]

My suggestions to replace it:

1. Member for less than 24 hours
2. Joined today (instead of the whole line)

Any better ideas? Reasons to keep the existing wording?